# Работа с файлами локализации WordPress

Tags: wordpress, локализация

Привет.

Делаю оплату на wordpress, сделал страницу все ок.

Но проблема в том что сайт на 3-х языках, а я на русском прям в шаблоне написал. Узнал что все находится в файлах типа **ru_RU.po**.

Нашел программу **poEdit**, но там вроде только редактировать. Думал вручную сделать, а там как-то все не понятно.

```
#: footer.php:25
#@ twentythirteen
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Главная"
```

Кроме того если подобным образом добавить информацию, указать файл, указать линию(ЗАЧЕМ???), то все равно не работает.

Вопрос в том как добавить туда свои слова?

Comment: ознакомьтесь, для начала, с [этим](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext), тогда хоть будете представление иметь об инструменте, который используется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рядом с фалом ru_RU.po находится скомпелированный файл ru_RU.mo именно из ru_RU.mo берутся данные для сайта.

Что бы перекомпелировать файл в Unix системе должна стоять утилита gettext.
Для компиляции войдите в папку где находится файл xxx.po, и выполняем команду:

```
msgfmt xxx.po -o xxx.mo
```

P.s.
Сделайте бекап файлов.

Answer (score 0):

в файлах языков, мы создаем одну и туже переменную, но задаем разные тексты, в зависимости от языка:

`ru_RU
 msgid "Home"
 msgstr "Главная"
 moi_text "Мой текст"`

`en_EN
 msgid "Home"
 msgstr "Main"
 moi_text "My text"`

а в шаблоне выводим нашу переменную `moi_text` и при переключении языков, вместо нее будет подтягиватся текст из нужного файла.

Comment: вот если честно не понял. как именно производить вызов на вашем примере? __('Home') ? То что вы написали немного отличается по формату от того что в файле , это допустимо?

Comment: я просто привел пример, а Вы пишите так, как в файле..  найдите где выводится `msgid` и сделайте по его примеру.

Comment: @M11 вообще есть статья на русском - http://domservisa.com/2009/05/21/rusifikaciya-wordpress-pravilnyj-perevod-temy-ili-plagina-dlya-cms/
почитайте, там все просто и понятно

Comment: только что понял что оно нигде не работает, нету с чего пример взять